# exception in mono using mvc3 and mysql.data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, mono, monodevelop, il

I get the following exception when attempting to instantiate a new `MySqlConnection` in an MVC3 app built on top of Mono (mono v 2.10.8.1, app is compiled for .NET 4)

> Invalid IL code in System.Data.Common.DbConnection:.ctor (): method body is empty.

I created another command line app and tried to connect and that worked fine.

I've tested this with MySql.Data 6.5.4 and 6.4.5. I'm referencing the following dll's from the mvc3 project:

- System.Web.Helpers
- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Razor
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor
- MySql.Data
- Microsoft.CSharp
- System
- System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
- System.Core
- System.Data
- System.Web
- System.Web.Abstractions
- System.Web.DynamicData
- System.Web.Extensions
- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.Services
- System.Xml
- System.Xml.Linq

Comment: For MVC2/3 projects, it is recommended you use Mono 3.0.

Comment: I am having this same issue, I am attempting to compile a console application with the mcs compiler using the MySql dot net connector as the library referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue trying to run a Mono app on linux because I deployed an incompatible System.Data.dll to the target system.

Installing the Mono System.Data package (apt-get install libmono-system-data4.0-cil) solved the problem for me.